MT4 transfers structure to C++ dynamic library, data error
I used visual studio to create an x86 dynamic library. There is a function in it that needs to pass a custom structure as a parameter to the DLL for processing. However, the value after passing it is incorrect.Below is my structure：
struct MarketData {
    int timestamp;
    char symbol[64];
    double open;
    double high;
    double low;
    double close;
};

Next is my test function:
MARKETDATA_API void testStruct(MarketData& md, double val)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "timestamp: " << md.timestamp << " open: " << md.open << " high: " << md.high
        << " low: " << md.low << " close: " << md.close << " symbol: " << md.symbol
        << " floag value: " << val;
    LOG(ss.str());
}

Call this function in MT4:
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
  {
   int timestamp = TimeCurrent();
   string symbol_str = Symbol();
   double open_price = iOpen(symbol_str, PERIOD_M1, 0);
   double high_price = iHigh(symbol_str, PERIOD_M1, 0);
   double low_price = iLow(symbol_str, PERIOD_M1, 0);
   double close_price = iClose(symbol_str, PERIOD_M1, 0);
   Print("timestamp: ", timestamp, " symbol: ", symbol_str, " open: ", open_price, " high: ", high_price, " low: ", low_price, " close: ", close_price);
   
   MarketData md;
   md.timestamp = timestamp;
   md.open = open_price;
   md.high = high_price;
   md.low = low_price;
   md.close = close_price;
   StringToCharArray(symbol_str, md.symbol);
   double val = 1.23;
   testStruct(md, val);
   return (rates_total);
  }

Below is my MT4 output and console printout：
MT4:2024.05.14 10:09:44.163 test XAUUSD,M1: timestamp: 1715659783 symbol: XAUUSD open: 2341.65 high: 2341.97 low: 2341.55 close: 2341.93
CONSOLE:timestamp: 1715659964 open: -1.78355e+259 high: -5.1647e-284 low: -8.67922e+209 close: 5.35754e-315 symbol: XAUUSD floag value: 1.23
Then I suspected whether it was an alignment problem and changed the timestamp type to double.
struct MarketData {
    double timestamp;
    char symbol[64];
    double open;
    double high;
    double low;
    double close;
};

After retesting, the MT4 print results and console print results are as follows:
MT4:2024.05.14 10:20:06.473 test XAUUSD,M1: timestamp: 1715660405.0 symbol: XAUUSD open: 2342.88 high: 2342.91 low: 2342.85 close: 2342.9
CONSOLE:timestamp: 1.71566e+09 open: 2342.88 high: 2342.91 low: 2342.85 close: 2342.9 symbol: XAUUSD floag value: 1.23
So passing character arrays or double type parameters alone does not cause problems, but why does encapsulation into a structure cause problems?

MARKETDATA_API void testStruct(MarketData& md -- Try passing a pointer across DLL and app boundaries, not references.  References are compiler (both compiler and options used to build the module) and version dependent.  Example:  MARKETDATA_API void testStruct(MarketData* md, etc.

After inspection, it was found that MQL4 uses 4-byte alignment, and the alignment method used by C++ is different from MQL4. The problem was solved after using #pragma push(4) and #pragma pop() to force 4-byte alignment.
